# Can I define <anything already been> in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```
.el {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 979px) {
    .el{
        padding: <anything already been> 10px 10px 10px;
    }
}
```

Is there something to use as `<anything already been>` ?

---

I can do that like this:

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
    .el{
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-buttom: 10px;
    }
}
```

But I just like to know is there any approach to do that in one line?

Comment: what do you mean by `anything already been`

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I mean *keep it everything currently is*. In this case it should be `20px`. Because I've initialized it `20px` already.

Comment: @MartinAJ inherit?

Comment: inherit doesn't work, because you're not able to apply other values to the other shorthand properties.

Comment: Not possible as anything you put there will overwrite the value that has already been set

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to state that no, it is not possible.

Inherit would be the sufficient replacement, but this cannot be achieved because inherit counts for all 4 properties of the shorthand. You cannot semi-overrule part of it by entering inherit randomly.

Besides, with padding, it will always be converted from `padding` to `padding-top`, `padding-left` etc etc. Which will (as @Pete stated) overrule the original value everytime.

You should stick with your second approach:

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
    .el{
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-buttom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: @uom-pgregorio you'll have to blame my copy/paste from OP there =).

Answer (score 3):

Theres no way to do what you want to do. You could get something closeish with [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) to achieve this.

For example:

```
.el {
    --paddingTop: 20px;

    padding: var(--paddingTop, 0) var(--paddingRight, 0) var(--paddingBottom, 0) var(--paddingLeft, 0);
}

@media (max-width: 979px) {
    .el{
        --paddingRight: 10px;
        --paddingBottom: 20px;
        --paddingLeft: 20px;
    }
}
```

This would be fine to use on 1 off situations but would give you way too much overhead to want to do this everywhere imo.

Comment: thanks ... honesty I've never seen such a thing in CSS. upvote

Comment: It is relatively new so browser support is a bit iffy if you need to support IE but it _is_ a solution. I'd always use @robberrrt's though

Comment: Well CSS variables used to have horrible support, but it seems like this is improving these days https://caniuse.com/#search=custom%20properties

Comment: Oh, @DanGamble sniped me there.

Comment: From what I've read, IE have no plans to implement support for them, if you are going this route you are better off using a css preprocessor like sass or less

Comment: IE will not be implementing them (Edge has in version 15).